# Oracle: Difference between DATE and TIMESTAMP(0)

Tags: oracle

What is the difference, if any, between DATE and TIMESTAMP(0) in Oracle? Both data types occupy 6 bytes, and contain date with time, but without fractional seconds and a timezone.

The TIMESTAMP was added to Oracle about 20 years after DATE to comply with ANSI standard. TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMP(6) can hold fractions of seconds, so it is different from DATE, but is there any difference between TIMESTAMP(0) and DATE?

Comment: Apart from the differences listed by MT0, have a look at [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref134)

Answer (score 4):

One is a `DATE` data type and one is a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

They both take up 7 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second).

The `DATE` will be implicitly formatted by the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter when it is displayed.

The `TIMESTAMP` will be implicitly formatted by the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter when it is displayed.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  dt DATE,
  ts TIMESTAMP(0)
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( dt, ts ) VALUES ( SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP );

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF6';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       DUMP( dt ),
       ts,
       DUMP( ts )
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DT                  | DUMP(DT)                            | TS                         | DUMP(TS)                            
> :------------------ | :---------------------------------- | :------------------------- | :-----------------------------------
> 2020-10-08T14:21:35 | Typ=12 Len=7: 120,120,10,8,15,22,36 | 2020-10-08T14:21:36.000000 | Typ=180 Len=7: 120,120,10,8,15,22,37
> ```

Functions that require a `TIMESTAMP` input won't perform an implicit `CAST` from a `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP`.

So:

```sql
SELECT FROM_TZ( dt, 'UTC' ) FROM table_name;
SELECT FROM_TZ( CAST( dt AS TIMESTAMP(0) ), 'UTC' ) FROM table_name;
SELECT FROM_TZ( ts, 'UTC' ) FROM table_name;
```

The first statement raises an `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got DATE` exception but the second and third works.

As mentioned by @WernfriedDomscheit in comments, arithmetic is also different between `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types. For example:

```sql
SELECT dt - dt,
       ( dt - dt ) DAY TO SECOND,
       ts - ts
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DT-DT | (DT-DT)DAYTOSECOND  | TS-TS              
> ----: | :------------------ | :------------------
>     0 | +00 00:00:00.000000 | +000000000 00:00:00
> ```

The top expression is `DATE - DATE` and the result is the difference in days (expressed as a `NUMBER` data type). However, the bottom expression is `TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP` and the result is an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type. It is possible to get `DATE` subtraction to output an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type but, as shown in the middle example, you need to explicitly state that that is the output you require.

Addition to a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` also has differences. For example:

```sql
SELECT dt + 1,
       dt + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
       ts + 1,
       ts + INTERVAL '1' DAY
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DT+1                | DT+INTERVAL'1'DAY   | TS+1                | TS+INTERVAL'1'DAY         
> :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :-------------------------
> 2020-10-09T19:52:21 | 2020-10-09T19:52:21 | 2020-10-09T19:52:22 | 2020-10-09T19:52:22.000000
> ```

Adding a number or an `INTERVAL` to both a `DATE` and a `TIMESTAMP` is both syntactically correct (but may not be as expected). If you look you will see that the output for adding a number or an interval to a date gives the same output in both cases. However, there is a difference between the output when adding a number to a timestamp compared to adding an interval to a timestamp; this is because you can only add numbers to date values and by adding a number to a timestamp then Oracle has performed an implicit cast from timestamp down to a date so:

```sql
SELECT ts + 1 FROM table_name
```

is effectively performing:

```sql
SELECT CAST(ts AS DATE) + 1 FROM table_name
```

So, if you want to perform arithmetic with a `TIMESTAMP` data type then use `INTERVAL` data types rather than numbers.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b6b90fc7b774de717a1b2fbf7d93c72)*